# Stripe API to retrieve all the events related to specific payment

Tags: stripe-payments

I wanted to retrieve all the events related to a transaction using payment_id. I see the dashboard itself is using this URL `https://dashboard.stripe.com/v1/events?include_only%5B%5D=data.id,data.created,data.livemode,data.api_version,data.data.object,data.is_object_log,data.is_summarized,data.is_unstable_event,data.object,data.pending_webhooks,data.request.id,data.request.idempotency_key,data.type,data.webhooks_archived,data.redaction.status,age_horizon_at,has_more,object&related_object=payment_id_here` for getting such information.

As this is the unofficial API and used by Stripe itself, I can not use it. I was not able to find the same thing in Stripe documentation. Any idea and suggestion to get the same data using official API?

Answer (score 1):

been looking at the same issue and found this API works:
https://api.stripe.com/v1/events?related_object=pi_XXXXXXXXX

you can use the limit=x as well
https://api.stripe.com/v1/events?related_object=pi_XXXXXXXXXXX&limit=1

Answer (score 0):

Stripe doesn't offer an API endpoint / parameter to retrieve all the events related to a specific payment. If you want to do so, you would have to save all the events upon receipt to your own database and perform your own tagging/filtering.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is implement stripe webhooks, catch the events and store them in your database. Once you get them in your database you can perform all the operations that you want.